# PHP: $_POST in switch statement a right way?

Tags: php, post, switch-statement

I'm using switch statement on **$_POST** method and my script runs correctly but I think my code is not in a right way.

*Here's my code:*

```
<?php

switch(isset($_POST))
{
    case isset($_POST['A']):
      //do something
    break;
    case isset($_POST['B']):
      //do something
    break;
    case isset($_POST['C']):
      //do something
    break;
}

?>
```

my **script** runs correctly but I think my switch statement is not *GOOD* enough. Is there more simplier way or **BETTER** way using **switch** statement and **$_POST** method?

Comment: Isset returns true or false, you should use an if/elseif statement for this.

Comment: Using `switch(true)` should do what you're after.

Comment: The statement is nice! +1

Comment: Are you *sure* this runs correctly?  I doubt this is doing what you think it's doing.  If you only tested *one* case for the `switch` then it's likely that you received the expected output, but not for the reasons you think.

Comment: so I can't used switch statement? is it better to use if/elseif statement?

Comment: @Detention No, this statement is nice and will work. But you must understand how it works

Comment: @Detention: You can use a switch, but I wouldn't suggest it in this case.

Comment: @David yes I'm sure it runs correctly and works correctly

Comment: @Detention Don't let you tell anything about using `if` here.. your `switch` is better

Comment: @hek2mgl: I think you're confusing code which is "clever and interesting" with code which is "clean and maintainable."  The two are very different things.

Comment: Unless those controls are checkboxes, then they will always be set when the form is submitted, so the first case will always fire.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: That depends on his form and how this is being POSTed.

Comment: @RocketHazmat From a POST form?

Comment: @DarylGill: Or an AJAX call, or something else.

Comment: P.S. `isset($_POST)` will *always* be `TRUE`.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: Only with some JS on the page that would remove or disable a control.  Still, ugly switch.

Comment: @David NO. Exactly the opposite is the fact. A `switch(true) ..` is much more readable and better maintainable than an endless `else if` .. `else if` ... Also it prevents the programmer from accidently modifying the value of variables which are used in a later `else if (...)` comparison. That's why I told the code is nice

Comment: `isset($_POST['something'], $_POST['something2'], $_POST['something3'], ...)` will return `TRUE` only if **all** vars are set.

Comment: The code is clearly easier to read than if-else statements, although maybe not on the first glance since we are so used to seeing ifs. The code is faster too for array > 5 since at this point the compiler starts using jumptables instead of just normal if-ese compares masked as switch.

Answer (score 8):

It's horrible but I prefer this than if-else-evil-chain:

```
switch(true)
{
    case isset($_POST['A']):
      //do something
    break;
    case isset($_POST['B']):
      //do something
    break;
    case isset($_POST['C']):
      //do something
    break;
}
```

Comment: if-else-evil? What are you talking about? Yeah `switch(true)` is pretty goofy.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Check my comment below the question

Comment: @hek2mgl Yeah I disagree. I don't get the "evil" thing at all. Code clarity is the goal? Or something else? To me it's fairly clear this is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Have you ever seen an `else if` construct which is spread across multiple hundreds of lines (not written by you and you have to maintain)? You'll will need be veerrry careful in order to don't change variables which are been used in a later `else if (` condition.. (x 100 lines below of course...) .. If you have done that you will understand the *evil*

Comment: @WesleyMurch: I don't like if-else-infinite chains and I don't like this switch(true) too. It's only a solution to a problem and in my opinion, this is clearer but as you wrote and I think the same, is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @hek2mgl I'm certain there's a better alternative to both of those things, details of course depend on the actual code.

Comment: @Detention No, your code isn't wrong. But you can replace `switch(isset($_POST))` by `switch(TRUE)` as `$_POST` will be always set

Comment: @WesleyMurch is there a better alternate way? rather than using **if/elsif** or **switch** ?

Comment: @WesleyMurch If you would throw away what you have originally learned about the `switch` statement for a moment you will confirm that it is best suited for this job. Better than `else if`.. Advantages would be more clear if we would have a look at a real world example

Comment: @Detention Use what works and is understandable. Every code snippet here including yours does the same thing with the exception of Lajos Veres's answer.

Answer (score 6):

check this out ;)

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {

         switch ($_POST) {
        case $_POST['A']:
            #do something;
            break;
        case $_POST['B']:
            #do something;
            break;
        case $_POST['C']:
            #do something;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you mean something similar?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['A'])){
 // do something
}
if(isset($_POST['B'])){
 // do something
}
if(isset($_POST['C'])){
 // do something
}

?>
```

(This executes all the different matching branches instead of only the first one. Change the non-first `if`'s to `elseif` if you want execute only the first matching branch.)

Comment: There's a difference here: if all 3 are set, "do something" will run for each one, unlike the OP's code which uses `break`.

Comment: I assumed "something"s are different.

Comment: I mean you need `elseif` for the same functionality as the OP's code.

Comment: @WesleyMurch what if I used **exit();** or **die();** it will run for for each one too right?

Comment: @Detention You don't want those, it will stop the entire script.

Answer (score 2):

A nice way of putting a `switch (){ case: }` method is:

```
if (condition){
   // Do Something    
}elseif(condition){
   // Do Something
}elseif(condition){
   // Do Something    
}
```

This chain, is horrible to look at, but something I would suggest using in your unique case, alternativley you could go with @lame-up-ducks answer, but this is what i'd personally recommend using

Comment: With a little improved formatting this seems like the clearest, most readable way to me. It's also the least amount of code.